# Cross-domain $.ajax() without "?callback=?"

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

Is possible use `$.ajax` without `?callback=`?

I'm trying to get a JSON response for this url http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/15b278a8-1356-4f7b-ba32-3c733c3d0aac.json?op=contacts, but, in the request, jQuery adds `?callback=` to the url, and therefor gets a different result.

The request is for a remote domain:

```
     $.ajax({ url: encodeURI("http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/15b278a8-1356-4f7b-ba32-3c733c3d0aac.json?op=contacts"),
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     type: 'GET',
     success: function(data){...});
```

Comment: $.ajax does not necessarily require a callback, but using jsonp does. That's the point of using jsonp.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - however, you have to have a browser that supports [CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) ([Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) and you need to ensure that the server is set up to allow requests from at least your domain by sending an [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) HTTP header.  Once you have both of those it is a simple matter of changing your `dataType` from `jsonp` to `json`.